# How to remove Ubuntu EFI system partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 alongside Windows 10. While installing I created swap area, EFI system Partition, home partition and root partition. 
Now, I want to remove the Ubuntu so in windows I deleted all the partition relating to Ubuntu. 
However the EFI system partition can't be deleted. So I searched it over internet and got a process which guides through the diskpart in terminal.

---

1. diskpart
2. list disk(EFI system partition was in volume 5)
3. sel vol 5
4. assign letter=Z:

after that I went to open a new powershell window where I cd over to the Z drive I created. Inside that was two folder Ubuntu and Boot, which I was little confused about. I rmdir both directory.

Going back to the diskpart, I tried to format the volume Z or say volume 5 in which EFI system partition is but was unable to delete that partition.

This is the image and 477 mb partition is the partition I want to delete. On right click it only shows help option.

[image]

How do i delete this partition?

Comment: You can only have one ESP - efi system partition per drive. But Windows may not realize you have two and does not let you remove the second one. Turn off boot flag and then you may be able to remove it. You can use Windows or gparted to change flag. http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: @oldfred is it possible to change boot flag with in windows while logged into windows?

Comment: I believe so. Windows calls it the active partition. But do not know all the details. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unmark-a-partition-as-active/40f6d20b-1514-42b6-8b14-c7fc18c6324a